# Vuejs import / load javascript file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need some help. I am trying to load my javascript file and listing to changing on checkbook when I click my checkbox to show or hide password. But for some reason it is not working. I have try everything, but out of ideas how to solve the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#showPassword').on('click', function () {
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
  $('#password').attr('type', 'text')
} else {
  $('#password').attr('type', 'password')
}
})



<template>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
<div class="col-md-12 content">
<div class="col-md-6 join-container" id="join-container">
  <form class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"
  >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control"
             id="password" v-model="password"
             placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group pl-0">
      <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
              id="showPassword" />
       <label class="form-check-label"
              for="show-password">Show Password</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Main from '../script/Index.js'

export default {
  name: 'Register',
  data: () => ({

 }),
methods: {
},
components: {
 Main
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend mixing jQuery and Vue

Comment: The jQuery is not mix with the vue code. The jQuery code is inside my Index.js file and I import that file in my vue.

Comment: I meant don't use both; just use Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery event handlers (the `$` bit) outside a script tag in a Vue component file. I wouldn't expect that code to do anything.

If you wanted that code to execute, you'd need it to be inside the `<script>` tags in your component. However, Vue already has event listeners ([link to documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)), including listening for clicks on elements. There is no need to use two frameworks for this.

To implement a rough show password button (using your existing markup), here's how I'd do it (removing extra markup to highlight the important Vue-logic):

```
<template>
<div>
  <input :type="passwordType" v-model="password">
  <input v-model="showPassword" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showPassword: false,
      password: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    passwordType() {
      if (this.showPassword) {
        return 'text'
      } else {
        return 'password'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not advisable to mix jQuery and Vue since they have separate lifecycles.

Vue is able to do everything you're after by itself.

Simply bind your checkbox state to a Vue `data` property and use that to determine the password field's `type`, eg

```html
<input :type="passwordFieldType" class="form-control"
       id="password" v-model="password"
       placeholder="Password">

<!-- snip -->

<input v-model="passwordFieldType" true-value="text" false-value="password"
       class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
       id="showPassword">
```

```js
data: () => ({
  passwordFieldType: 'password'
})
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    password: '',
    passwordFieldType: 'password'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<form class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="app">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input :type="passwordFieldType" class="form-control" id="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group pl-0">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input v-model="passwordFieldType" true-value="text" false-value="password"
             class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="showPassword" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="show-password">Show Password</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```